# Kotlin 1.6.0 breaks proguard?

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

After updating my Android app from Kotlin 1.5.21 to Kotlin 1.6.0, my proguard rules stopped working (i.e. they are ignored). This caused some reflection code to break on release mode. Downgrading to Kotlin 1.5.21 fixes the problem.

Are there any known problems with Kotlin 1.6.0 and proguard ?

Googling around, I see that there are other related problems (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70449911/674487), [this](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1368), [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47945)).

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you use moshi im your project?

Comment: Is there an error message? Can you run gradle with a lower log level/in debug mode? This may be worthy of reporting to the maintainers of proguards.

Comment: I don't use Moshi. There is no error message whatsoever. I don't have much knowledge about the Android apps build system, but I will try to implement a minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the version of R8 bundled with the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP).

Following the advice in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70331139/674487), I explicitly set `com.android.tools:r8:3.0.77` in my gradle configuration file.

```
dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools:r8:3.0.77")
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
}
```